# Web based stats for linux

Tags: linux, graph, statistics, memcached, database-administration

Can you recommend a web based script that will output graphs for some of the following system stats on linux servers:

- Network usage
- Disk usage
- CPU usage
- Memcache usage
- User logins
- HTTP usage
- FTP usage
- database stats

etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munin + plugins.

Some examples :

- [Memcache Plugin](https://github.com/mhwest13/Memcached-Munin-Plugin)
- [Mysql Plugin](https://github.com/kjellm/munin-mysql)
- [Disk Usage](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/disk-day.html)
- [Http Usage](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/http-day.html)
- [Logins (on system)](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/logins-day.html)
- [Postgres Usage](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/postgresql-day.html)
- [Cpu Usage](http://demo.munin-monitoring.org/system-day.html)

And you can write your custom [muning plugins](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins)